# How to Bind DataGrid Header

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

Cannot get the `ComboBox` in the `DataGridTextColumn.Header` to bind.
The first stand alone `ComboBox` binds fine.
Fields is just `Public List<String>`.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Fields}"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyRows}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="80" Binding="{Binding Col1}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Header1" />
                        <ComboBox Width="60" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Fields}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

```
private List<string> fields = new List<string> { "aa", "bb", "cc" };
public List<string> Fields { get { return fields; } }
```

even tried making Fields a Property of MyRow

Comment: I was wrong, apparently the DataContext is not inherited as expected. Peter Hansen's workaround is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you use the DataContext on the DataGrid, which has been inherited from the Window.

```
<ComboBox Width="60"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Fields, 
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
```

Comment: I was close once.  Did not have the RealtiveSource in the ItemsSource.  Thanks